# Website optimization for IE <10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, optimization, quirks-mode, ie-compatibility-mode

I created a website using HTML 5 and it works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 10. If I'm running the website in Compatibility mode the layout is all messed up.

Only if I change Document Mode from IE5 quirks to another value inside Developers Tool it's working perfectly.

Is there someone who can give me some hints or some tips&tricks to make it work properly.

You can find the website here: http://www.westmotors.ro/beta

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you be using (IE5) Quirks Mode?  Do you have a DOCTYPE on your page?  Your page works fine in IE9.

Comment: Yes I do have DOCTYPE on my page. But when someone tested the website on IE9 it didn't worked. I changed from (IE5) Quirks Mode to IE99 Standard and it worked. And now the big problem is that I have to avoid this kind of situations. e.g. Someone who has the browser set on on Quirks Mode

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice website where you can see the HTML5 readiness of any browser:
http://html5readiness.com/

In addition I would strongly recommend you to use the Modernizr javascript plug-in  in order to make your site compitable: http://modernizr.com/

Last thing, try to find some "polyfills" for html5 features you cannot use in your site "the native way"

Comment: I'll will start to see if I can manage to solve it with Modernizr. Thank you.